# Delay response or No response from Nodejs to poastgres using postman after 10 api hits

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

I am running the below code it giving me a response for the first 10 hits. After that, it takes a lot of time to return the response or no response

**Code:**

```
var db = require('../config/dbConfig')
var sendResp = require('../helper/response').sendRsp;

module.exports.saveSubscriberDetail = async (req,res) => {

let objDetailsInput = Object.assign({}, common.detailsInput);
    errors = []
    let finalData;
    objDetailsInput = req.body;
    var reqObj = {};
    try {
        var client = await db.connectDatabase();
        
        
        if (objDetailsInput.subscriberDetails.p_address.country) {
        
         const rows = await client.query('SELECT * FROM country where country_code = $1', [objDetailsInput.country])
          if(rows)
           {
                 sendRsp(res,201,"Success",rows);
            }
            else
            {
               sendRsp(res,500,"Internal Server Error")
             }
          }
            } catch (error) {
        throw (error)
    }
    };
```

**Postman Response:**
[image: PostManResponse]

**Visual Studio Code Response:**

[image: VSCResponse]

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you using any local tunnel tool ?

Comment: no I am using postgres sql as db and postman for sending request

Comment: What module do you use to connect to postgres? What is `db`? Is `connectDatabase` a function you have written and if so how does it look like?

Comment: The shown code indicates that you don't close the connection, and either the connection pool of the module runs out of available connections or you hit the connection limit for the user with which you connect to postgres. But without knowing further details it is not possible to tell you how to solve the problem correctly.